# PHP and ssh2, not loading

Tags: php, apache, libssh2

I've installed the ssh2 extension for PHP.  Running:

```
# php -m | grep ssh2
```

returns

```
ssh2
```

And in phpinfo() I have:

```
libSSH Version:     libssh2/1.4.2
```

But there's not actual extension installed.  I have confirmed my php.ini has

```
extension=ssh2.so
```

in it, but still no extension.

Advice welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it - I upgraded to PHP 5.4 yesterday, and there was a new extension needed for that.  Should have twigged that before!